# Will a join still work if the column being joined is null?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, null

I've got this stored procedure, and when I add the join I get no results. Is this because the column used for the join condition, ForClientID, is null? Would that affect the results of the table? If i select the table with Appointment.ForClientID instead of Client.Name, the rest of the table loads with the ForClientID column being null. Thanks in advance, this is an amazingly helpful community.

```
Create procedure GetAppointmentsByProfessionalName(@ProfessionalName varchar(256))
as
    declare @ProfessionalID uniqueidentifier
    set @ProfessionalID = (select UserId from aspnet_Users where UserName = @ProfessionalName)

    select  Appointment.AppointmentID as 'Appointment ID', 
            Client.Name as 'Client Name',
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Appointment.ProposedDate,111) as 'Date', 
            CONVERT(CHAR(8), Appointment.ProposedTime, 114)as  'Time', 
            Appointment.ClientDescription as 'Client Notes', 
            Appointment.Confirmed as 'Confirmed Appointment'
    from Appointment join Client on Client.ClientID = Appointment.ForClientID
    where Appointment.ForProfessionalID = @ProfessionalID
go
```

Comment: Why not create a join between `Appointment` and `asp_Users` in the main query, use the `@ProfessionalName` parameter in the `WHERE` clause and lose the local variable `@ProfessionalID`? SQL optimizers tend to prefer one big query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a re-write using an `OUTER JOIN` to take account of the `Appointment.ForClientID` being `NULL`-able and replacing the local variable `@ProfessionalID` with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAppointmentsByProfessionalName
@ProfessionalName VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT Appointment.AppointmentID AS 'Appointment ID', 
          COALESCE(Client.Name, '{{NO CLIENT}}') AS 'Client NAME',
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Appointment.ProposedDate,111) AS 'Date', 
          CONVERT(CHAR(8), Appointment.ProposedTime, 114)AS  'Time', 
          Appointment.ClientDescription AS 'Client Notes', 
          Appointment.Confirmed AS 'Confirmed Appointment'
     FROM Appointment 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Client 
             ON Client.ClientID = Appointment.ForClientID
          INNER JOIN aspnet_Users
             ON aspnet_Users.UserId = Appointment.ForProfessionalID
    WHERE aspnet_UsersUserName = @ProfessionalName;

END;
```

Answer (score 3):

The behavior surrounding NULLs is the primary difference between the different types of JOIN.  Read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 , which while being Wikipedia is a surprisingly good article on the topic.

Comment: I went with a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get the required results. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, useful read!

Comment: That is not a cross join, that is a standard inner join in SQL-89 syntax.  And I find it unlikely that a cartesian product (ie, cross join) is actually what he wants.